# Why do class compile when package name is wrong in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I just saw my class compile with wrong package name when I was writing code in kotlin. Any idea how and why that happened.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by wrong package name?

Comment: Class is in package com.xyz.fragment, but class has something like com.xyz.activity defined in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello there in `kotlin` package not works like they works in `java`

In kotlin you can set any **package** with any **name** any **where**

For example  this is your package hierarchy

com->android->kotlin->ui->activities

In where you have file `MainActivity.kt` and `Utils.kt`

In your `MainAcitivity` file you can set this `package` name as

```
package com.android.kotlin.ui.activities
```

And on the same time you can set your Utils file package to

```
package com.android.kotlin.utilities
```

So why this happen and Kotlin complier not generate an error and how it works fine?

In kotlin you can say folder package are not really exists you can save your file to any folder like your **abc** file in **xyz** folder and your **efg** file into **vwx** folder and you can set both of your file package to `com.android.lmnop` package and you can access properties, top level function classes **etc** directly without any problem and without compile time error! hope you understand.

And you can even get knowledge about kotin packaged from below mentions resource.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/kotlin-from-scratch-packages-basic-functions--cms-29445

Answer (score 0):

The package declaration tells the compiler which package the file belongs to. That will be the file's package, even if the file location doesn't match.
More informations [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html).